# OPENUI5: Named Model Aggregate Binding Data is not showing

Tags: sapui5

after reading [Multimodel Support](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f1156f6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) I tried to implement it.
When using a named model the binding happens but the data is not displayed.

// Controller

```
sap.ui.controller("view.apps.Apps", {

    onInit : function () {
        var oAppsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/apps.json");
        this.getView().setModel(oAppsModel, "apps");
    }
});
```

// View

```
sap.ui.jsview("view.apps.Apps", {

    getControllerName: function() {
        return "view.apps.Apps";
    },

    createContent: function(oController) {

        var oInboxList = new sap.m.List({
            inset: true,
            id: "appsList",
            headerText: "Apps"
        });

        oInboxList.bindItems("apps>/items", function(sID, oContext) {
            return new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                title: '{name}',
                description: '{name}'
            })
        });

        var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Apps",
            content: [oInboxList]
        });

        return oPage;
    }
 });
```

// apps.json

```
{
    "items": [{
        "name": "ABC",
        "view": ""
    }, {
        "name": "DEF",
        "view": ""
    }]
}
```

This View produces two empty ListItems. When I change the model to an unnamed model and I update the BindPath to /items the List gets properly populated and the values are displayed. Any ideas on whats wrong with my coding? I'd really like to use the named models.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, just reread the documentation. It is necessary to prefix ALL bindings with the name of the named model when using a named model for binding.

```
oInboxList.bindItems("apps>/items", function(sID, oContext) {
        return new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: '{apps>name}',
            description: '{apps>name}'
          })
    });
```

Comment: Yes but only because of the named setModel in your controller. If you just do `this.getView().setModel(oAppsModel)` you can skip the name in every binding. The naming is just an option when using several models.

Comment: Indeed. The provided sample is just a striped down version of the full coding.